# Protect against client-initiated renegotiation DoS in OpenSSL/Python

Tags: openssl, python

According to https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2011/10/31/tls-renegotiation-and-denial-of-service-attacks, servers supporting SSL/TLS connections and allowing client-initiated renegotiations are susceptible DoS attacks by a client who continually renegotiates the ssl connection. I was able to get the CPU to spin up to about 15% with this "exploit" script I wrote:

```
(while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do echo R; sleep 0.01; done) | openssl s_client -cert agent.crt -key agent.key -connect 192.168.110.100:4959
```

Anyway, how do I disable client-initiated renegotiations for OpenSSL (which I am using through Python's `openssl` library)?

Comment: Most webservers (IIS, nginx etc) do not allow client-initiated renegotiation by default.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple way to disable client initiated renegotiations at the server side. The usual way is to detect and count renegotiations by using SSL_CTX_set_info_callback with an appropriate function and to close the connection if too much renegotiations happen.

A code example how this can be done within C can be found at https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2726#issuecomment-3901047. The set_info_callback function should be available within python's OpenSSL interface too, but I'have no running code for this. If you need help with the Python specific part you might better ask at stackoverflow then.